# Screen width overflow on handheld devices

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design

I am currently struggling with the CSS of my mobile-view pages (handehlds, for example iphone in portrait view). Strangely, there is an approximate margin of 90 pixels to the right of the body/content container. I simply do not get the reason for that - any idea?

See it here:
http://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=http%3A//bigbertha.golfanatics.de/testsite/&w=320&h=480&a=33&s=1

URL: http://bigbertha.golfanatics.de/testsite/index.php

Thank you in advance for any hints! best regards, Ralph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do, is this.

```
body {
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

This will remove the scroll bars on mobile. (from left to right)

**Edit:** I took another look at your site, and noticed that you have this on your html element

```
html {
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Remove that line, and voila :)

Comment: natewiley and also @srekoble - thank you both for the suggestion. It sounded logical to me, but sadly does not change anything: the problem persists...(you can see the updated CSS by checking the links in my original question). I simply don't understand that. Any other idea?

Comment: p.s. I just found something that might have to do with the problem: in Firefox and Chrome, a SECOND vertical scrollbar appears on the right hand side of the screen (so there are two). However, the scrollbar seems to be disabled...

Comment: @RalphNohe natewiley is right remove overflow-y: scroll from html

Comment: @natewiley thank you for the tipp, I altered the html element CSS and now the second scrollbar is not shown anymore. Good! The first problem still remains. And although I have added the overflow-x:hidden to the body of each page, left-right-scrolling is still possible in mobile devices, with that annoying blank space on the right hand side..

Comment: @srekoble thanks to you also, perhaps you still have any other idea on the main problem which was not solved by adding the overflow-x:hidden......

Comment: @RalphNohe You haven't removed the overflow-y: scroll you just add overflow-y: auto which isn't going to solve your problem. And you haven't add display: none; to #roksearch_result , This causes your problem.

Comment: @srekoble yes I have added the display:none to #roksearch-result, it is only entering into effect when the screen width is below 767px (in my responsive CSS settings). When looking into it with screenfly I do not see that element anymore. So that should be okay, or not? What to do in order to remove the overflow-y:scroll ? - I do not find the CSS file for that, and thought it might work to simply override it with 'auto'. I have not added the original crappy setting overflow-y:scroll to the html element, this came with the template............

Comment: You don't need screenfly, you can just your browser. If you open Google Chrome and push f12 for developer tools it will tell you the width of the window in the corner while you re-size.

Answer (score 0):

You have explicit width to `#roksearch_results` and you just apply `opacity: 0;`. You have to `display: none;` to this div ( or change the width to 100%).

```
#roksearch_result {
 display: none;
}
```

And you also give scew transform to socialmedia navigation which goes beyond your width. You could overflow: hidden the navigation but this would hide the corners of the scewed socials so I would suggest to `overflow-x:hidden` to the body.

```
#body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: p.s. I just found something that might have to do with the problem: in Firefox and Chrome, a SECOND vertical scrollbar appears on the right hand side of the screen (so there are two). However, the scrollbar seems to be disabled....